# Is it possible to edit the properties of a single tile in JavaFX tilepane?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, tile

Is there a way in JavaFX to get/change the properties of a single tile in the tilePane layout? More specifically, I am looking to change the color of a single tile.

If this isn't possible, what are some alternatives I could try?

Comment: You can get any child of tilepane with getChildren().get() you need its index as argument. Other way is getting a reference like any other object

Comment: Yes, you can do this.

Comment: If you're wondering if you can change the style of a tile _without a child `Node`_, then no. The `TilePane` layout doesn't really have "physical" tiles. It takes its list of children and arranges them into a tiled layout as best it can. So, if you want to change the style of a "tile", then you need to place a child `Node` in the `TilePane`, then style said `Node`. This is true of most, if not all, layouts (e.g., `GridPane`).